# Extract contents within html tags using R

Tags: html, regex, r

I am now trying to extract contents between specific html tags, e.g.:

```
<dl class="search-advanced-list">
<dt>
<h2><a id="/advanced-search?intercept=adv&amp;as-advanced=+documenttype%3Asource title:%22ADB%22&amp;as-type=advanced" name="ADB">ADB</a></h2>
</dt>
<dd>Allgemeine deutsche Biographie. Under the auspices of the Historical Commission of the Royal Academy of Sciences. 56 vols. Leipzig: Duncker &amp; Humblot. 1875&#8211;1912.</dd>
<dt>
<h2><a id="/advanced-search?intercept=adv&amp;as-advanced=+documenttype%3Asource title:%22AMS%22&amp;as-type=advanced" name="AMS">AMS</a></h2>
</dt>
<dd>American men of science. J. McKeen Cattell, ed. Editions 1&#8211;4, New York: 1906&#8211;27.</dd>
<dt>
<h2><a id="/advanced-search?intercept=adv&amp;as-advanced=+documenttype%3Asource title:%22Abbott%2C+C.+C.+1861%22&amp;as-type=advanced" name="Abbott__C__C__1861">Abbott, C. C. 1861</a></h2>
</dt>
<dd>Abbott, Charles Compton. 1861. Notes on the birds of the Falkland Islands. Ibis 3: 149&#8211;67.</dd>
...
</dl>
```

[link](https://www.darwinproject.ac.uk/bibliography)

I plan to extract contents within `<h2>` `</h2>` and contents within `<dd>` and `</dd>`. I searched the stackOverFlow for similar questions, but still cannot figure it out, is there anybody who has a simple way to solve this question using R?

Comment: do not put image as i have no time to write your code again and to test..provide your code as simple text

Comment: Try reading the webpage in using the `XML` package

Comment: it is _highly_ unlikely you did _any_ searches for anything related to this on SO

Comment: @hrbrmstr, actually I did, but most of them are not specific to R, and the questions specific to R is not dealing with the specific and subtle question as I have. Sorry I just saw your answer, really sorry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This creates a two column matrix `m` whose first column is `h2` and whose second column is associated `dd` values.  Since there is no information in the question on the form of the input we have assumed that the input is a string `Lines` but the `htmlTreeParse` line can be changed appropriately if not.  Try `?htmlTreeParse` for more info.

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlTreeParse(Lines, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

f <- function(x) cbind(h2 = xmlValue(x), dd = xpathSApply(x, "//dd", xmlValue))
L <- xpathApply(doc, "//h2", f)
m <- do.call(rbind, L)
```

Here we display the `h2` column and the first 10 characters of the `dd` column:

```
> cbind(h2 = m[,1], dd = substr(m[,2], 1, 10))

      h2                   dd          
 [1,] "ADB"                "Allgemeine"
 [2,] "ADB"                "American m"
 [3,] "ADB"                "Abbott, Ch"
 [4,] "AMS"                "Allgemeine"
 [5,] "AMS"                "American m"
 [6,] "AMS"                "Abbott, Ch"
 [7,] "Abbott, C. C. 1861" "Allgemeine"
 [8,] "Abbott, C. C. 1861" "American m"
 [9,] "Abbott, C. C. 1861" "Abbott, Ch"
```

This is the input used above:

```
Lines <- '<dl class="search-advanced-list">
<dt>
<h2><a id="/advanced-search?intercept=adv&amp;as-advanced=+documenttype%3Asource title:%22ADB%22&amp;as-type=advanced" name="ADB">ADB</a></h2>
</dt>
<dd>Allgemeine deutsche Biographie. Under the auspices of the Historical Commission of the Royal Academy of Sciences. 56 vols. Leipzig: Duncker &amp; Humblot. 1875&#8211;1912.</dd>
<dt>
<h2><a id="/advanced-search?intercept=adv&amp;as-advanced=+documenttype%3Asource title:%22AMS%22&amp;as-type=advanced" name="AMS">AMS</a></h2>
</dt>
<dd>American men of science. J. McKeen Cattell, ed. Editions 1&#8211;4, New York: 1906&#8211;27.</dd>
<dt>
<h2><a id="/advanced-search?intercept=adv&amp;as-advanced=+documenttype%3Asource title:%22Abbott%2C+C.+C.+1861%22&amp;as-type=advanced" name="Abbott__C__C__1861">Abbott, C. C. 1861</a></h2>
</dt>
<dd>Abbott, Charles Compton. 1861. Notes on the birds of the Falkland Islands. Ibis 3: 149&#8211;67.</dd>
</dl>'
```

Comment: I have  found the html source, check the link added to the question.

Comment: Use `u <- "http://www.darwinproject.ac.uk/bibliography"; doc <- htmlTreeParse(u, useInternalNodes = TRUE)` in place of the `doc<-` line in the answer.  The input seems quite large so this might take some time to process.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck many thx, u not only solve my question, but also make the result in a nice table way...

Answer (score 3):

Or, doing the scraping the proper way:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html("https://www.darwinproject.ac.uk/bibliography")

h2 <- html_text(html_nodes(pg, "dt > h2"))
head(h2)
## [1] "ADB"                            "AMS"                           
## [3] "Abbott, C. C. 1861"             "Abich, O. H. W. 1841"          
## [5] "Accum, Frederick. 1820"         "Acevedo Moraga, Fernando. 1987"

dd <- html_text(html_nodes(pg, "dd"))
head(dd)
## [1] "Allgemeine deutsche Biographie. Under the auspices of the Historical Commission of the Royal Academy of Sciences. 56 vols. Leipzig: Duncker & Humblot. 1875–1912."                                                                
## [2] "American men of science. J. McKeen Cattell, ed. Editions 1–4, New York: 1906–27."                                                                                                                                                 
## [3] "Abbott, Charles Compton. 1861. Notes on the birds of the Falkland Islands. Ibis 3: 149–67."                                                                                                                                       
## [4] "Abich, Otto Hermann Wilhelm. 1841. Geologische Betrachtungen über die vulkanischen Erscheinungen und Bildungen in Unter- und Mittel-Italien. Braunschweig."                                                                       
## [5] "Accum, Frederick. 1820. A treatise on the art of brewing, exhibiting the London practice of brewing porter, brown stout, ale, table beer, and various other kinds of malt liquors. London: Longman, Hurst, Rees, Orme, and Brown."
## [6] "Acevedo Moraga, Fernando. 1987. La Escuela de Minas de la Serena. In La Serena University, edited by Claudo Canut de Bon: 1–18. Chile."
```

I feel compelled to include a snippet from their [ToS](https://www.darwinproject.ac.uk/terms-of-use):

> Subject to statutory allowances, extracts of material from the site may be accessed, downloaded and printed for your personal and non-commercial use and you may draw the attention of others within your organisation to material posted on the site. You may not:
>
> - use any part of the material on the site for direct or indirect commercial purposes or advantage without obtaining a licence to do so from the University or its licensors
> - you may not modify or alter the paper or digital copies of any material printed off or downloaded in any way
> - sell, resell, license, transfer, transmit, display in any form, perform, hire, lease or loan any content in whole or in part printed or downloaded from the site
> - systematically extract and/or re-utilise substantial parts of the content or material on the site
> - create and/or publish your own database that features substantial parts of this site.
>
> If you print, copy, download or use any part of the site in breach of these terms of use, your right to use the site will cease immediately and you must at the option of the University return or destroy any copies of the material you have made.

Comment: many thx. I have already sent them an email about the copy right of their materials.

Answer (score 1):

```
htmlpattern <- "</?\\w+((\\s+\\w+(\\s*=\\s*(?:\".*?\"|'.*?'|[^'\">\\s]+))?)+\\s*|\\s*)/?>"
plain.text <- gsub(htmlpattern, "\\1", txt)
cat(plain.text)
```

Note : txt is html text