# Delete exclude specific strings

Tags: r

I would like to exclude  string ""and "<"

```
year  name
1   <b>abc<
2   <b>judy<
3   <b>lin<
```

I would like the output to look like this:

```
year  name
1   abc
2   judy
3   lin
```

Comment: This looks like html, if yes, use a parser: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32921284/680068

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `str_extract` the part you're interested in:

```
library(stringr)
df$name <- str_extract(df$name, "(?<=<b>)[^<>]+(?=<)")
```

How this works:

- `(?<=<b>)`: if you see `<b>` on the left (positive lookbehind) ...
- `[^<>]+`: ... match any chars one or more times that are **not** `<` or `>` provided ...
- `(?=<)`:  ... you also see `<` on the right (positive lookahead)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` here:

```r
df$name <- sub("^<b>(.*)<$", "\\1", df$name)
```

Comment: sorry,I just got it wrong,exclude string "<b>"and "<".

Comment: Check the updated answer.